# Поменять местами введённые значения (Blur)

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно поменять местами два введённых значения. Не могу понять, где ошибка, что `onBlur` не срабатывает.

```js
function replaceValues(obj)
{
 var buffer = obj.valueAlpha.value;
 obj.valueAlpha.value = obj.valueBeta.value;
 obj.valueBeta.value= buffer;
}
```

```html
<FORM name="form" onblur="replaceValues(form)">
<input type="text" size=7 name="valueAlpha">
<input type="text" size=7 name="valueBeta">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У события `onblur` нет фазы всплытия (как и у `onfocus`). Поэтому, Вы не можете отловить его с помощью делегирования, как в вашем примере.

Используйте события `onfocusout` и `onfocusin`, для достижения цели:

```js
function replaceValues(obj) {
  if (obj.valueAlpha.value == '' || obj.valueBeta.value == '') { return }
  var buffer = obj.valueAlpha.value;
  obj.valueAlpha.value = obj.valueBeta.value;
  obj.valueBeta.value = buffer;
}
```

```html
<FORM name="form" onfocusout="replaceValues(form)">
  <input type="text" size=7 name="valueAlpha">
  <input type="text" size=7 name="valueBeta">
</FORM>
```

`onBlur` срабатывает только на том элементе, где произошло событие. Поэтому, нужно прописывать такой обработчик каждому элементу:

```js
function replaceValues(obj) {
  if (obj.valueAlpha.value == '' || obj.valueBeta.value == '') { return }
  var buffer = obj.valueAlpha.value;
  obj.valueAlpha.value = obj.valueBeta.value;
  obj.valueBeta.value = buffer;
}
```

```html
<FORM name="form">
  <input type="text" size=7 name="valueAlpha" onblur="replaceValues(form);">
  <input type="text" size=7 name="valueBeta" onblur="replaceValues(form);">
</FORM>
```

Comment: Да, это достигает внешнего выполнения поставленной задачи, но как сделать тоже самое используя Blur?

Comment: @ti-phonex Дополнил ответ.